# How to place controls in div tag and design like this

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a requirement where I need to place the controls like this in design:

```
  label1 textbox1    label5 textbox5
  label2 textbox2    label6 textbox6
  label3 textbox3    label7 textbox7
  label4 textbox4    label8 textbox8
```

Now I need to place all the controls in a div tag, how can I do it? I am using vs 2008 and asp.net

Comment: <div> label1 textbox1</div>
<div style='float:left'> label5 textbox5</div>
use float: left to make it on second column and then adjust it with padding and margins

Answer (score 2):

Here is the css

```
<style>
#txtbx1div
{
  width:200px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}

#txtbx2div
{
  width:200px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
</style>
```

The html part..Remember the values posted  in this example are taken as an array txtbox[]..you you can rename it  as you wish.

```
<div id="txtbx1div">
  <label>label1</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label2</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label3</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label4</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
</div>

<div id="txtbx2div">
  <label>label5</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label6</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label7</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
  <label>label8</label>
  <input type="text" id="textbox[]" />
</div>
​
```

Comment: As long as you specify format as a code block, SO would display that HTML just fine. Much more usable than an image. (Also, you could look into creating a jsFiddle account, where you could create and link examples.)

Comment: I think div tag and some other tags are  not allowed here            http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Those tags only apply to formatting your own answer. You can include any markup for any language within a code block (any text block preceded with 4 spaces). I've placed an edit in queue to demonstrate.

Comment: I actually tried to indent it by four spaces ,didn't work it seems.Anyway thanks for the info.

Comment: There is also a format option on the toolbar when editing the text, the { } icon, which you can use to select a block and specify code in that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        <div class="left_align">
            label1</div>
        <div class="left_align">
            textbox1</div>
        <div class="left_align">
            <div class="left_align">
                label5</div>
            <div class="left_align">
                textbox5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css style sheet is:

```
.left_align
 {
        float:left;
 }
```